# Problem with data type casting and calculating in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have the code look like this:

```
CASE
           WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR
                        FROM REPORTING_DATE) >= EXTRACT(YEAR
                                                              FROM ('2018/11/09 14:11:31' :: DATE)) THEN EXTRACT(YEAR
                                                                                                    FROM REPORTING_DATE)
           WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR
                        FROM ('2018/11/09 14:11:31' :: DATE) - EXTRACT(YEAR
                                                          FROM REPORTING_DATE)) >= 2 THEN EXTRACT(YEAR
                                                                                                        FROM ('2018/11/09 14:11:31' :: DATE))
           WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR
                        FROM REPORTING_DATE) < EXTRACT(YEAR
                                                             FROM ('2018/11/09 14:11:31' :: DATE))
                AND EXTRACT(YEAR
                            FROM REPORTING_DATE) - EXTRACT(YEAR
                                                                 FROM ('2018/11/09 14:11:31' :: DATE)) < 2
                AND EXTRACT(MONTH
                            FROM ('2018/11/09 14:11:31' :: DATE)) < 6 THEN EXTRACT(YEAR
                                                                      FROM REPORTING_DATE)
           ELSE EXTRACT(YEAR
                        FROM ('2018/11/09 14:11:31' :: DATE))
```

After proceeding, it shows message:

> Operator does not exist: date - double precision

At the location:

```
WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR
                        FROM ('2018/11/09 14:11:31' :: DATE) - EXTRACT(YEAR
                                                          FROM REPORTING_DATE)) >= 2
```

Athough i have cast the string:

> 2018/11/09 14:11:31 --> to date type

and:

> EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ('2018/11/09 14:11:31' :: DATE) ) --> EXTRACT(YEAR FROM...) --> return double value type

But it still shows that message.
Anyone could tell me what did i do wrong. and how could i fix it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a parentheses in wrong place. It should be

```
EXTRACT( YEAR FROM ('2018/11/09 14:11:31' :: DATE)
        ) - EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATE REPORTING_DATE) >= 2
      --^                                       --^
   --put here                                  --not here
```